# Как послать POST запрос?

Tags: javascript

Я делаю POST запрос в delphi `URL + Body(JSON Object)` и все работает.

Теперь пытаюсь сделать тоже самое в JavaScript

Вариант 1:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://URL/login", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200
    {console.log(xhr.responseText)}
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"email": "test@yandex.ru", "password": "1234"}));
```

Вариант 2:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://URL/login",
    data: JSON.stringify({ email: "test@yandex.ru", password: "1234" }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(){console.log("success")},
    error: function(){console.log("error")}
});
```

Ошибки в консоле:

> - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://URL/login' from origin 'http://myURL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>     resource.
> - error
> - POST http://URL/login net::ERR_FAILED

Как сделать запрос что бы он прошёл? 
Серверная часть не моя, менять, добавлять ничего не могу

Comment: Если нет доступа к серверу, то никак. Разве что через прокси-скрипт на своем сервере.

Comment: бывает еше ublock блочит запросы. (если он конечно установлен)

Comment: @hindmost а почему клиент написаный на делфи не блокируется? Ведь там тоже самое

Comment: _а почему клиент написаный на делфи не блокируется?_ Потому что он работает только у вас, а не в браузере у постороннего человека, и не подвергает опасности чужой компьютер. Почитайте про [Same Origin Policy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Comment: @hindmost а нельзя такое в JavaScript добиться, мне в ответ нужно получить простой текст(json). он ведь не может подвергнуть опасности

Comment: Я уже написал, что нельзя. Same Origin Policy не позволит, а она во всех браузерах действует. Разверните свой клиент на делфи на сервере (на том же домене что ваш сайт) и обращайтесь к нему из JavaScript.